# Angular 4 directive output cause delay when show into component with *ngFor

Tags: angular, material-design, directive

I'm working on an address prediction directive (using material design 2). This uses the Google AutocompleteService but when it emits the predictions the component that uses this delay around of 10 or 25 seconds renders into view. I'm using `console.log()` in the component and this prints the array elements but not the view. Why doesn't it log the view?

In my logic, when the user releases the keypad after 3 seconds a request for predictions will be sent to google's service with the the input-address (contain directive). Then when it returns data, it creates an array of 'Prediction' and this emits with the `@Output() onpredict`. The component prints this into console but only after some seconds it shows in the view.

#### The View

```
<md-input-container class="full-width">
  <input type="text" mdInput addressPrediction (onpredict)="showPredictions($event);" (onsearching)="searching = true;" placeholder="Ingrese una dirección">
  <md-hint align="end" *ngIf="searching">Buscando...</md-hint>
</md-input-container>

<div *ngIf="predictions.length > 0 && !searching">
<md-nav-list>
  <div *ngFor="let prediction of predictions">
    <md-list-item>
      <h4 md-line>{{ prediction.name }} </h4>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-divider></md-divider>
  </div>
</md-nav-list>
</div>
```

#### The Component

```
export class InputAddressComponent {

  predictions: Prediction[] = [];
  searching: boolean;

  constructor(){}

  showPredictions(predictions: any[]): void {
    this.searching = false;
    this.predictions = predictions;
    console.log(this.predictions);//this show elements but the view not print after some seconds
  }

}
```

#### Directive

```
@Directive({ selector: '[addressPrediction]' })
export class AddressPredictionDirective {

  @Output() onpredict: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter<any[]>();
  @Output() onsearching: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  resolveSuggestions: (predictions, status) => void;
  autocompleteService: any;
  search: any;
  input: string = '';
  country: string = 'cl';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef){}

  ngOnInit(): void {


    this.autocompleteService =  new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

    this.resolveSuggestions = (predictions, status) => {

      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert('AutocompleteService error: '.concat(status));
        return;
      }

      let places: Prediction[] = [];

      for(let i: number = 0; i<predictions.length; i++){
        let place: Prediction = { id: predictions[i].reference, name: predictions[i].description };
        places.push(place);
      }
      this.onpredict.emit(places);

    };
  }

  @HostListener('keyup') onKeyUp() {
    if(this.el.nativeElement.value.trim() != this.input.trim()){
      this.input = this.el.nativeElement.value;
      if(this.input.length > 4){
        this.searchAddress();
      }
    }
  }

  @HostListener('keydown') onKeyDown() {
    if(this.search){
      clearInterval(this.search);
      this.search = null;
    }
  }

  private searchAddress(): void {
    this.onsearching.emit(true);
    this.search = setTimeout(() => {
      this.autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions({
        input: this.input,
        componentRestrictions: { country : this.country }
      }, this.resolveSuggestions);
      clearInterval(this.search);
    }, 3000);
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you used Chrome Console and network tab. It's probably Google servers overloaded...

Comment: I'm using the console ("Im use 'console.log' into component and this print the array elements but the view not.") and this print elements, the network delay 1ms to response. Thanks for answer!!!

Comment: yes iḿ using the network tab

Comment: @MatiasAguirreLuco It might be because of the animation as you are using material design

Comment: Could it perhaps be something to do with changeDetection, or content projection then?

Comment: I will test with a component without 'Material Design' that uses the same directive to check if the problem is Material

Comment: @JGFMK I am not changing the data passed to the directive

Comment: @MatiasAguirreLuco I actually wasn't thinking about the directive. More md-nav-list md-list item. Do they have that? Also totally left field there's no bizarre/funky animate css delay stuff?

Comment: in html (onsearching)="searching = true;" Is that syntax ok? I'd have though you'd have been somehow using an observable boolean...

Comment: md-nav-list is a material2 component, i tried with a normal ul li and get the same result. About the onsearching i only need change the searching todo true but Will try move this to method

Comment: Have you tried to manually trigger changedetection. You can try and import `ChangeDetectorRef`, inject it in constructor and run `detectChanges()`

Comment: Sorry @JGFMK but I ignore your suggestion of changeDetection since I confused it with OnChanges, effectively this helped me to show the results but I do not understand well how it works, therefore I will start to study changeDetection, thanks for the answers!!

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f

Comment: Thanks man!! you helped me a lot!!